# Issue while using the preg_Replace() function in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have used the preg_Replace function in CorePHP as follows:

```
$d [] = preg_Replace("^0", "", $a);
```

But I'm getting the following error as:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^'
```

What does the *No ending delimiter* mean? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly change your syntax to one of the following two options:

```
$d[] = preg_replace("/^0/", "", $a);
```

or

```
$d[] = preg_replace("(^0)", "", $a);
```

### Demo

Comment: It works. Thanks alot.